# Getting error while publishing data to GCP IoT core and Pub/Sub using C SDK

Tags: c, google-cloud-platform

I am running an example code from Google IoT C SDK which is iot-device-sdk-embedded-c.

```
iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/examples/iot_core_mqtt_client
```

I am running the code using the following commands

```
./iot_core_mqtt_client --project_id=project-aura-249003 --device_path=projects/project-aura-249003/locations/asia-east1/registries/Linux_PC/devices/linux_pc --publish_topic=projects/project-aura-249003/topics/Example --publish_message=Hello_world --private_key_filename=./ec_private.pem
```

I am getting error, below

`IoTC Embedded C Client Version: 1.0.2`
`connected to mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog:8883`
`publishing msg "H" to topic: "projects/project-aura-249003/topics/Example"`

`connection closed - reason 17 : !`

The error means `IOTC_CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER_ERROR`

I found a solution from git where they told to try to change the topic to `events` or `states` so i tried with that as well by the same error is coming.

You can find the SDK [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c)

What am i missing here?

Please help me with this

Thank you
Harsha

Comment: It seems the issue is on peer side, can you check this [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c/issues/76) and the other particularly related to this error [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58799227/iotc-connection-reset-by-peer-error-in-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c) on Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that we need to provide the topic name properly. In this we are suppose to provide the MQTT topic which in this case is

`--publish_topic=/devices/linux_pc/events`
(OR)
`--publish_topic=/devices/linux_pc/state`

should work fine.

The topic which was provided `projects/project-aura-249003/topics/Example"` is wrong.

Format Topic = `/devices/<Device-ID>/events` or `/devices/<Device-ID>/state`